# Ordering Joomla Search Results by Section Name

Tags: mysql, search, joomla

Im just diving into Joomla with a co-worker and we need to be able to order search results by the section name in our main results page.

As of right now, I have tried a few different things, including editing the SQL Statement in the content-fulltext.php.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I am very new to integrating/manipulating Joomla, so thanks for bearing with me.

Fillip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any extension that orders results in such a way(but you can try your chance [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search)), so you have to code it yourself.

Changing the sql query is the simplest solution in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I was figuring the same thing. I did edit the content.php (in plugins>search>content.php) and it works fine now. I changed the default in that ordering case statement to "sectionid DESC". Thanks for the confirmation!